# How to remove header and footer records of a flat file using UNIX shell script?

Tags: unix, scripting, shell

I am having a flat file as give below. How do I delete the header and footer from the file using UNIX shell script and rewrite the same file.

```
9 20050427 HEADER RECORD
0000000 00000 000000000 123456 00 654321 DATARECORD
0000000 00000 000000000 123456 00 654321 DATARECORD
0000000 00000 000000000 123456 00 654321 DATARECORD
0000000 00000 000000000 123456 00 654321 DATARECORD
6 20050427 TRAILER RECORD
```

Thanks,
Arun

Answer (score 12, accepted):

... and with `sed`:

As [@Baramin](http://users/491264/baramin) noted: the least amount to type is `sed '1d;$d'`, here is how it works:

### By line number

```
sed -i'' -e '1d' -e '$d' yourfile
```

`1d` deletes first line `$d` deletes last line.

### Or by pattern

```
sed -r -i -e '/^[0-9] [0-9]{8} HEADER RECORD$/d' \
          -e '/^[0-9] [0-9]{8} TRAILER RECORD$/d' yourfile
```

`-r` is needed for the `{8}` extended regular-expression.

### Or both

If you are super pedantic, and want to cover your ass in the most thorow way:

```
sed -r -i.bak -e '1{/^[0-9] [0-9]{8} HEADER RECORD$/d}' \
              -e '${/^[0-9] [0-9]{8} TRAILER RECORD$/d}' yourfile
```

---

The `-i''` will change `yourfile` in-place. Drop it if you want to store the output in another file (e.g. with `> outputfile` at the end of your line).

Comment: Nice one. can be summed up this way : sed '1d;$d' file

Answer (score 10):

```
tail -n +2 filename | head -n -1
```

don't have my unix box to test on so those numbers might be 1 or 2, i can't remember if they are bot 1, both 2 or what but i ise this all the time (i just experement right before i run the cmd to see if its 1 or two... the `tail ...` should remove the first line and the `head ...` should remove the last

Answer (score 4):

Very simple solution for your question

```
sed -i '1d;$d' yourfile
```

Answer (score 3):

This is ugly, but it seems to work, at least on your input:

```
f='test.txt'; g=`wc -l $f`; h=`echo $g | cut -d ' ' -f1`; head -n $((h-1)) $f | tail -n $((h-2))
```

f is the name of your file.  I couldn't work out a quicker way to get rid of the filename from the output of wc.  Someone should be able to beat this.

If you want to rewrite the same file, just redirect the output of the command:

```
f='test.txt'; g=`wc -l $f`; h=`echo $g | cut -d ' ' -f1`; head -n $((h-1)) $f | tail -n $((h-2)) > $f
```

Comment: Good one.. but had an issue while deleting the last line. But worked fine.

Comment: Redirect the file into `wc` to eliminate the filename: `wc -l < "$f"`

Answer (score 2):

OTOH, a couple of commands that will clip the first and last line of a file.

- `head -n -1` will clip the last line of a file.
- awk can be used to clip the first line of the file with a command like `awk 'NR>1 {print}'`

Alternatively, you can use `grep -v` to filter out the first and last lines if they can be reliabily identified by string matches.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option that is simpler (if your tail supports `+` semantics)

`tail -n +2 <file> | head -n -1`

Answer (score 0):

I got it in this way.. and thanks all for your help.

```
wc -l fileman |awk '{print $1-0}' |xargs -i head -{} filename | sed -n '2,$p' > filename
```

Comment: To avoid `wc -l file | awk '{print $1}'` do this: `wc -l < file`.  When wc reads from stdin, it won't print the filename.

Answer (score 0):

Just to throw out a couple more alternatives:

```
awk -v last=$(wc -l < filename) 'NR == 1 || NR == last {next} {print}' filename
awk 'NR==1 {next} NR==2 {prev = $0; next} {print prev; prev = $0}' filename
```

To overwrite the current file, if you're not using `sed -i`:

```
( whatever | pipeline ) <filename >filename.tmp && 
ln filename filename.bak &&
mv filename.tmp filename
```

Comment: Thanks for shedding some light on this... Thanks all.