# How to Remove header and footer from Dataframe?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am reading a text (not CSV) file that has header, content and footer using

```
spark.read.format("text").option("delimiter","|")...load(file)
```

I can access the header with `df.first()`.  Is there something close to `df.last()` or `df.reverse().first()`?

Comment: I would think that the most efficient way to do this would be not in spark.  I would do it in a preprocess step using a shell script.  Here are some ideas: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193817/how-to-remove-header-and-footer-records-of-a-flat-file-using-unix-shell-script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sample data:

```
col1|col2|col3
100|hello|asdf
300|hi|abc
200|bye|xyz
800|ciao|qwerty
This is the footer line
```

Processing logic:

```py
#load text file
txt = sc.textFile("path_to_above_sample_data_text_file.txt")

#remove header
header = txt.first()
txt = txt.filter(lambda line: line != header)

#remove footer
txt = txt.map(lambda line: line.split("|"))\
    .filter(lambda line: len(line)>1)

#convert to dataframe
df=txt.toDF(header.split("|"))
df.show()
```

Output is:

```
+----+-----+------+
|col1| col2|  col3|
+----+-----+------+
| 100|hello|  asdf|
| 300|   hi|   abc|
| 200|  bye|   xyz|
| 800| ciao|qwerty|
+----+-----+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the file is not so large we can use collect to get the dataframe  as iterator and the access the last element as follows:

```
df = df.collect()[data.count()-1]
```

avoid using `collect` on large datasets.

or

we can use take to cut off the last row.

```
df = df.take(data.count()-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to above answer, below `solution fits good` for files with `multiple` `header` and `footer` lines :-

```
val data_delimiter = "|"
val skipHeaderLines = 5
val skipHeaderLines = 3

//-- Read file into Dataframe and convert to RDD
val dataframe = spark.read.option("wholeFile", true).option("delimiter",data_delimiter).csv(s"hdfs://$in_data_file")

val rdd = dataframe.rdd

//-- RDD without header and footer
val dfRdd = rdd.zipWithIndex().filter({case (line, index) => index != (cnt - skipFooterLines) && index > (skipHeaderLines - 1)}).map({case (line, index) => line})

//-- Dataframe without header and footer
val df = spark.createDataFrame(dfRdd, dataframe.schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file has JSON header and Footer,
Spark SQL way,

Sample Data

```
{"":[{<field_name>:<field_value1>},{<field_name>:<field_value2>}]}
```

Here the header can be avoided by following 3 lines (Assumption No Tilda in data),

```
jsonToCsvDF=spark.read.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("delimiter", "~").load(<Blob Path1/ ADLS Path1>)

jsonToCsvDF.createOrReplaceTempView("json_to_csv")

spark.sql("SELECT SUBSTR(`_c0`,5,length(`_c0`)-5) FROM json_to_csv").coalesce(1).write.option("header",false).mode("overwrite").text(<Blob Path2/ ADLS Path2>)
```

Now the output will look like,

```
[{<field_name>:<field_value1>},{<field_name>:<field_value2>}]
```