# Apache Spark - How to skip header and footer lines

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Assume that there is a Big file with `top 3 lines as header` and `last 3 footer lines`. `How to remove them using Apache Spark.`

In `Hive`, we can use table properties `tblproperties` `("skip.header.line.count","3"`)  and `("skip.footer.line.count","3")`

Do we have similar properties in Spark(I don't see any in the documentation). Let me know what is the best way?

Comment: I have added answer to your question to skip multiple header and footer lines @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47126936/how-to-remove-header-and-footer-from-dataframe/56875499#56875499